# C# and VB Class Private Variable Naming Practices and the "_" Character

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, class, private

> *Let's be clear: I'm not looking for an opinion, but an answer, an actual documented source or reference if possible. (Preferably something from MSDN?)*

In .NET when creating a class, the basic structure I follow goes along the lines of:

- Creating private variable fields.
- Defining the class properties using get/set.
- Creating the constructors.
- Adding extra class methods for database functionality.
- Misc functionality.

How I used to name my private variables:

```
private string _myString;
```

How I currently name my private variables:

```
private string iMyString;
```

I have been told that using the "_" character for private variable declarations has negative effects. which I then changed my practice to use the "i" character. I find that using the same character for these declarations helps with the speed of creating class properties, and overall development time.

**My question is:** *What is the industry standard to the class private variable naming structure? AND, Why is using the "_" character considered a bad practice?*

I've done quite a bit of google searches and even on the MSDN website the pages I viewed had their examples change regularly and thus inconsistent.

I'm not sure if this is considered a problem per say, but I tend to practice quality code.

Comment: ["The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from."](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum) - there's not an industry standard.  Only opinions... I would ask what "negative effects" using underscores has?  I use them all the time.

Comment: As far as I know there is no harm in using underscores.   More important than what you decide to do is to make sure that your set of standards are used in a consistent way.

Comment: You no longer need backing fields and getters/setter for properties if you use Auto Implemented properties.  The compiler supplies an implicit `_propName` variable for you (so a leading `_` it cant be *too* awful).  After than VB and C# diverge.  VB allows you to access the implicit field anywhere, while it is hidden in C#.  BTW [per se](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_se)

Comment: __camelCase__ for fields and __PascalCase__ for function members that's the convention. I wouldn't recommend using prefixes such as `i' or `_`

Comment: Why do *we* have to produce irrefutable proof of something when your question is based on "I've been told" with not a single link to anything that backs up your claims?

Comment: MSDN has many suggestions on naming conventions. The environment you are in as well as if you are continuing existing code also come into play. Here is a general guideline link but again MSDN does have loads of resources on this subject. http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Comment: If you aren't using [Allman indenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style), you are wrong! (j/k)There are some common practices, but there are a ton of standards that can be used. This possible answers are absolutely opinion based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [.NET foundation coding style guidelines](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md):

> We use `_camelCase` for internal and private fields and use `readonly` where possible. Prefix instance fields with `_`, static fields with `s_` and thread static fields with `t_`.